# ASP: Safety settings on this computer prohibit accessing a data source on another domain

Tags: asp-classic

when i am clicking on button to load a drop down, i have to access database of another server, then i am having the following error

**Safety settings on this computer prohibit accessing a data source on another domain**.

```
"../data.asp?SQL=SearchNumber%20'%25"+txtSearchDeptNumber.value+"%25'"
```

after much googling i found a solution - in IE adding this link to Trusted sites.
but it is not accepted because as client cant do this settings. So, i need some other solution than adding it to trusted sites.